# pushViewController slowly

Tags: ios, swift

mycode:

`self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
   NSLog("finish pushViewController")`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    NSLog("start viewDidLoad")
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSLog("end viewDidLoad")
}
```

log :

`2016-07-18 15:40:55.060 KaXin[64190:12458086] finish pushViewController
 2016-07-18 15:40:56.470 KaXin[64190:12458086] start viewDidLoad
 2016-07-18 15:40:56.471 KaXin[64190:12458086] end viewDidLoad`

between "finish pushViewController" and "start viewDidLoad" 
it takes 1.4 seconds.

what does it does?

how do I fix it?

ios 9.2, xcode:7.3

only first time push  this viewcontroller, it takes long time

Comment: What's inside your `init` method?

Comment: Heave you tried to profile it with instruments?

Comment: You found a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I've found that this normally happens when the ViewController that you're trying to push has code in the `viewDidLoad` that is taking a lot of time to execute. Please note that when pushing a new ViewController, it waits for the code in `viewDidLoad` to execute before showing the view.

Comment: Is the `pushViewController` function called on the main thread? Also, are you doing anything in `viewWillDissapear`?

Comment: I carefully screened the various elements, I found if I add the textview  on the view , it become very slow。。。。